# TW-ELEMENTS REACT Carousel doesn't start INTERVAL always FALSE, wrong configuration

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, slide

there is a problem with configuration that receive tw-elements.

Here the import:
import 'tw-elements';

Usage:

`....<div data-bs-ride='carousel' data-bs-interval='1000' id='carousel' className='carousel slide carousel-fade relative'>....`

The slide is showing and also the indicators, on click it works, but it doesn't starts AUTOMATICALLY.

In debugging mode if we look inside config, there is an error:

The config is

```
{
    "ride": "carousel",
    "interval": false,
    "target": "#carousel",
    "slideTo": 1
}
```

so why interval is set to false?

If I set new config it seems it takes them

`<div data-bs-ride='carousel' data-bs-interval='1000' data-bs-touch='true' data-bs-pause='hover' data-bs-wrap='true' id='carousel' className='carousel slide carousel-fade relative'>`
on the class carousel:

```
{
    "ride": "carousel",
    "interval": false,
    "touch": true,
    "pause": "hover",
    "wrap": true,
    "target": "#carousel",
    "slideTo": 1
}
```

Any idea?